# Check if website is in the blocked list

Tags: php, regex, oop, url

Am creating a class that handles redirection to exterior locations. I created a method called `isBlocked` which returns a boolean result. This function works as follows:

It loops through the `$_blocked` variable and compares is the input string is found, it it is it returns true otherwise false. Bellow is the actual incase my explanation is not enough.

```
public static function isBlocked($location)
{
     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof(self::$_blocked); $i++)
     {
         if(self::$_blocked[$i] === $location)
         {
             return true;
         }
         else 
         {
             return false;
          }
     }
}
```

This works perfectly, the problem comes when for example, lets say "google.com" is on the list and the input is "www.google.com", it will return false. This is obvious since am using the identical operator `===`.

Question is the following: Is there any function in PHP that work with URLS apart from `url_encode` & `url_decode`? I obviously can create a regular expression but let me know if there is any other approach to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is any subdomain from a domain allowed for any site? If so, then simply take off and use only the domain and TLD part. If not, then you should add the allowed subdomains. You could create some kind of wild card matching as well, however that would perhaps be your regular expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard

Comment: i konw the filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)
validate if the string is a valid url

Comment: @Jacinto Yes filter_var will validate. But aim not validate)

Comment: This doesn't solve your question, but you should remove the `return false;` statement. Use `foreach()` instead of `for()` and you can completely remove the loop if you use `in_array()`.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to add the else enclosure. Just noticed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs to me that the match is backwards, since it's a many to one, with the one matching a (sub)part of any in the stack. So, in that case we can use a `strpos()` (in lieu of a regular expression):

```
function find_reverse_match($needle, $haystack) {
    $i = 0;
    $c = count($haystack);

    while ($i < $c) {
        if (strpos($needle, $haystack[$i++]) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/69ot4O

Comment: I came with a different a approach, I instead block website based on their IP. Thanks for the help, certainly gave more knowledge on how I would do this.

Answer (score 1):

i just take example: 
[Php Search_Array using Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592120/php-search-array-using-wildcard)
that wrote @JaredFarrish and adopt for this particular case:

```
<?php

function isBlocked($location)
{
    $blocked = [
        'google.com',
        'www.google.com',
        'play.google.com',
        'developers.google.com',
    ];
    $matches = preg_grep("/^(www)?$location$/", $blocked);
    if (empty($matches)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

print isBlocked('play.google.com'); // 1
print isBlocked('www.google.com'); // 1
print isBlocked('google.com'); // 1
print isBlocked('stackoverflow.com');  // 0
```

And the answer: you should write regular expression)

Answer (score 1):

There is no php function to replace only first occurrence in a string, so preg_replace() and in_array() will do the job:

```
$blocked = array(
    'www.google.com',
    'yahoo.com'
);

var_dump( in_array( preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', 'google.com' ), preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', $blocked ) ) ); // true
var_dump( in_array( preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', 'www.yahoo.com' ), preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', $blocked ) ) );  // true
var_dump( in_array( preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', 'www.facebook.com' ), preg_replace( '/^www\./', '', $blocked ) ) );   // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to string replace the www.?

```
public static function isBlocked($location)
{
     for($i = 0; $i < sizeof(self::$_blocked); $i++)
     {
         if(self::$_blocked[$i] === str_replace("www.","",$location))
         {
             return true;
         }

             return false;
     }
}
```

Psuedo code.

NVM. Seem you said you can do expression

Maybe use

```
parse_url
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: str_replace would be not good, because lets say is the website am blocking is www.www.com the result would be .com